# How we can use IS NULL in query

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, dynamic

In this case i want to null check by using column IS NULL..here column specify uniquename.
Uniquename is a integer column.

```
filterExpression = objColumnSettings.UniqueName  + ' <> ' + objColumnSettings.FilterValue + ' AND ';
```

Here i have done like this.
This works but i want to use column IS NULL rather than ISNULL(column, value)

```
filterExpression = " ISNULL( " + objColumnSettings.UniqueName + " , 0 ) " + ' <> ' + objColumnSettings.FilterValue + ' AND ';
```

Please suggest
Thanks in advance;

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
 filterExpression = objColumnSettings.UniqueName + " IS NUL OR " + objColumnSettings.UniqueName  + ' <> ' + objColumnSettings.FilterValue + ' AND ';
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Its works. Thanks!!!